# jQuery plugin boiler plate - private method with bound scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking at the plugin boiler plate for jQuery plugins, I find it ok but there is one major flaw in the design or maybe just something I can't figure out.

When I author plugins at the moment, it is easy for me to define publicly exposed methods and private methods that only the plugin has access to.

When I tried to do something similar in the boiler plate I was thwarted.

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

// Create the defaults once
var 
    pluginName = "defaultPluginName",
    defaults = {
        propertyName: "value"
    };

// The actual plugin constructor
function Plugin ( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
        this.defaults = defaults;
        this.name = pluginName;
        this.init();
}

Plugin.prototype.init = function() {
    console.log('init')
    console.log(this)
    this.yourOtherFunction();
}
Plugin.prototype.yourOtherFunction = function () {
    console.log('yourOtherFunction')
    console.log(this)
    this.yourOtherFunction2();
}
Plugin.prototype.yourOtherFunction2 = function () {
    privateFunction().bind(this)
}

var privateFunction = function() {
    console.log('private')
    console.log(this)
}   

// A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
// preventing against multiple instantiations
$.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) {
    return this.each(function() {
        if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
            $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
        }
    });
};

})( jQuery, window, document );

$(document).defaultPluginName()
```

Anyway you can see the function 'privateFunction' it's scope is to the window object, but what I want to be able to do is scope it to the Plugin instance, or basically 'this' from the prototype methods.

**What I don't want to do, is pass the scope into each private function as a function argument!**

So how can I bind the scope?

```
Console output

init
Plugin { element=document, settings={...}, defaults={...}, more...}
yourOtherFunction
Plugin { element=document, settings={...}, defaults={...}, more...}
private
Window index.html <-- I want Plugin, not window
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
Plugin.prototype.yourOtherFunction2 = function () {
    privateFunction().bind(this)
}
```

With

```
Plugin.prototype.yourOtherFunction2 = function () {
    privateFunction.apply(this,arguments);
}
```

Comment: Just a quick note (because it tripped me up), `arguments` is an array.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `privateFunction` and **then** binding `this` as scope for its result. 
So use (as said by @Khanh_TO):

```
Plugin.prototype.yourOtherFunction2 = function () {
    privateFunction.apply(this,arguments);
}
```

Instead of:

```
Plugin.prototype.yourOtherFunction2 = function () {
    privateFunction().bind(this)
}
```

**More details:**

`bind` returns a **copy** of the function on which is called (the result of `privateFunction` in your case) after applying the scope you've passed in (`this` in your case). What `bind` does is something like:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(scope) {
    var _function = this;
    var _args = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length-1; i < len; i++){ _args[i] = arguments[i+1]; }
    return function() {
        // returns the same function on which is called (not the same Function object, but
        // another with same properties) with 'this' equal to the first parameter and
        // the remaining specified parameters as parameters of the function returned
        return _function.apply(scope, _args);
        }
}
```

eg. `myFunction.bind(newScope, param1, param2, ...)` -> returns an anonymous function which in turns returns the function `myFunction(param1, param2,....)` with set `this = newScope`.
So, as a proof of concept, also this code would have worked:

```
Plugin.prototype.yourOtherFunction2 = function () {
    privateFunction.bind(this)();
}
```

but you should use the first one since the last one does the same thing with extra passages.